# Div with centered text and floating elements

Tags: html, css

I have a `<footer>` at the bottom of my page. In this element, I want there to be a couple of `<p>`s that are centered inside the footer, and I want a block image link to be in the default `float: left` position in the footer. The floating block image is pushing my centered text to the right.

How do I keep my text centered within the `<footer>`, regardless of where the block image link is?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out as I was asking the question...

1. `footer{ position: relative; }`
2. `#blocklink { display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 0; }`

The text will stay centered with `text-align: center;` and the block element will be in the upper left corner.

Comment: inline-block is probably not necessary